# How do you compute Cross Correlation,Coherence and Mean Dealy?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, macroeconomics

I have been researching about economic forcasting using NBER type of analysis. It says about computing Cross Correlation, Coherence and Mean Delay of turning points then use them to determine which variable is leading, I have no problem with that since I have a program which can compute them.

My problem is that I dont have any algorithm or method which say how exactly to do it by hand. I have been searching for them for many days but still gotten no luck.

I will be grateful if anyone could provide me the algorithm, method of computing Cross Correlation, Coherence and Mean Delay or paper about NBER method.